# How to use a function in C that takes a function callback as an argument from dll file in Python code?

Tags: c, python-2.7, visual-c++

I have a function in C that takes a function callback as an argument in dll. It is OK for MFC and below is C code

```
void OnReceive(unsigned char* pReportBuf, int nReportLen, int nReportCount, SYSDELTA_TIME timeStamp) {

    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < nReportCount; iCount++) {

        BYTE *Buf = new BYTE[nReportLen + 1]; 
        memcpy(Buf, &pReportBuf[iCount*nReportLen], sizeof(BYTE)*nReportLen);
        SYSDELTA_TIME *sTime = new SYSDELTA_TIME;
        memcpy(sTime, &timeStamp, sizeof(SYSDELTA_TIME));

    }

}
res = InputRawRegHIDCallback(OnReceive);
```

Now I need to move above code to Python, but I don't know how to code
callback function to Python code. Could anyone help me to code???

Thank you for your great help.

BR,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ctypes, you can [wrap/annotate the callback function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) with type information using CFUNCTYPE so they can be called from the C library.